# Export Laravel Excel Data horizontally

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, fast-excel

I'm using rap2hpoutre/fast-excel library for exporting the information I need. Currently, with basic settings, I receive my data in the excel document in the following format:

```
Questions
First Question
Second Question
Third Question
```

What I want to get is:

```
Questions    First Question    Second Question      Third Question
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from its README page, there are less features in fast-excel compared to laravel-excel and i'm afraid that specifying cell value is the feature it misses.